# Word Riddler - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

When we start, I'm an animal inside an animal.

I got a name, just gotta build it.

Change a letter and double one that I have, roll me around, oh wait, don't take that!

Alright let's come back to the big state because I'm not a fan of that!

Now that we're here, let's look ahead.

I guess you need me before all else.

**What am I?**

**HINT**

> If making a building is something you wish, you'd better use me in order to flourish.

**HINT 2**

> Based in ND but part of SK, I help with farms in the U S of A.

Comment: Only reasonable [google result](http://farmandranchguide.com/news/livestock/south-korea-nd-beef-packing-plant-moving-ahead/article_912b3a43-aec5-5ce9-9fdc-a769efa54381.html) :p

Comment: Keep searching :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are

> a **Bobcat**

When we start, I'm an animal inside an animal.

> Bobcat has "cat" inside "bobcat".

I got a name, just gotta build it.

> Bobcat has got the name "Bob" in it.
>  Just gotta build it presumably references **[Bob the Builder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-P2-Nmk1uFQ)**.

Change a letter and double one that I have, roll me around, oh wait, don't take that!

> `bobcat` → `bobccat` [double c] → `oobccat` [`b`→`o`] and anagram to `tobacco`
>  and "roll around" is both anagrind and play on words for rolling tobacco.
>  Thanks @M Oehm for contributing this in the comments.

Alright let's come back to the big state because I'm not a fan of that!

> (From OP:) "Let's come to the big state" is a reference to the song "Ohio (Come back to *Texas*), and you are not a fan of the Ohio BOBCATS!

Now that we're here, let's look ahead.
I guess you need me before all else.

> (From OP:) Look ahead means scouting, and in boy scouts, the [BOBCAT badge](https://meritbadge.org/wiki/index.php/Bobcat_badge) is the first badge required.

HINT

> `If making a building is something you wish, you'd better use me in order to flourish.`
>  Bobcat, for construction.

HINT 2

> `Based in ND but part of SK, I help with farms in the U S of A.`
>  The **[Bobcat Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobcat_Company)** fits this description.

Comment: The thing that you shouldn't take could be tobacco: Duplicate the c, change one b to an o and scramble. And the "roll around" could hint at rolling cigarettes.

Comment: @MOehm Ooh! Thanks, I looked at a lot of words but missed that one.

Comment: Well, I'm not super sure it's correct, because it also works the other way round: Duplicate the o and change a b to a c.

Comment: Right on :) The 4th and 5th lines fit better than the description you gave, but if you want I'll be willing to edit it with the right reasoning

Answer (score 4):

**Very Partial**

When we start, I'm an animal inside an animal.

> This has multiple possibilities like -
>
>  F**ox** , Kan**gar**oo, Rein**deer**, Num**bat**, Dor**mouse**, Bob**cat**

Change a letter and double one that I have, roll me around, oh wait, don't take that!

> If I take **Fox** $\rightarrow$ **Fol**(Replace a letter) $\rightarrow$ **Fool**(Double letter o) $\rightarrow$ **Fool Around**?

Now, I'm not sure what needs to be done for the next step. Also, not sure if the second step is right or wrong. Hope someone else can figure it out.

Comment: "Roll me around" might mean to anagram it. Just realized this after reviewing my post from yesterday.

Comment: An **ant**eater is an animal in an animal in a double sense (the ant is in the anteater's stomach).

Answer (score 4):

Potential answer with not-quite-complete reasoning:

> Aardvark

When we start, I'm an animal inside an animal.

> Start with meadowlark. Meadowlark is an animal with **owl** inside it.

I got a name, just gotta build it.
Change a letter and double one that I have, roll me around, oh wait, don't take that!

> Change the l to a v and double the first a: Me**aa**dow**v**ark.
> Not sure about this piece, but add an **r** so you have **me** and **r** (for "roll") "around" the double letter: **me**aa**r**dvark.
>  Now remove "ow" for "**o**h **w**ait" => Meaardvark.

Alright let's come back to the big state because I'm not a fan of that!

> Not sure about this part. Maybe just that we're looking at the whole word again instead of the individual pieces?

Now that we're here, let's look ahead.
I guess you need me before all else.

> Looking ahead, past the "me" at the beginning, so drop the "me" and get "aardvark".

I feel like this is right but my reasoning is off in a few places.

Comment: This is certainly some good logic, but it's not the answer I was looking for. My answer fits every part of the riddle perfectly (at least I hope so) :-)

Answer (score 1):

I Am a...

> **DNA**

I'm an animal inside an animal.

> Live inside body

I got a name, just gotta build it.

> Deoxyribonucleic acid , build helical chains

Change a letter and double one that I have, roll me around, oh wait, don't take that!

> GC base pair with three hydrogen bonds. Bottom, an AT base pair with two hydrogen bonds.

Now that we're here, let's look ahead.

I guess you need me before all else.

> A hereditary material in almost all other organisms.

Comment: Nope, sorry not it :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm just gonna guess on the word being

> **BABY**

An animal inside an animal:

> I'm just assuming that humans could be considered to be an animal

I got a name, you just gotta build it:

> Name given on birth perhaps
>
>  Not sure about the word as I dont know what things are called in English, but roll the baby around and dont take it's feeding bottle or pacifier(according to google translate)

Alright let's come back to the big state because I'm not a fan of that:

> Dont know what come back to the big state means

Now that we're here, let's look ahead:

> To the future

I guess you need me before all else:

> Need babies to not get extinct

Comment: This is good logic, but not what I'm looking for sorry. Try following Techidiot's partial answers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are

> A Head.

Every part of the clue seems to fit, but the letter-scrambling bit seems a bit arbitrary.

Reasoning: (Starting from the bottom)

I guess you need me before all else.

> I guess I need my head. Ahead means "before all else".

Now that we're here, let's look ahead.

> Direct mention of "ahead"

Alright let's come back to the big state because I'm not a fan of that!

> Nobody likes big-headedness

I got a name, just gotta build it.

Change a letter and double one that I have, roll me around, oh wait, don't take that!

> Since this bit is so very flexible, there are most likely several ways to end up at whichever word from an animal. Here's one that ends up in "A Head": **Hare** -> (change a letter) **Hade** -> (double the a) **Haade** -> (roll around, as in anagram) **Ahead** -> (oh wait, take another anagram) -> **A Head**

When we start, I'm an animal inside an animal.

> A hare is an animal inside a harehound, for example.

Well, that's the best I've got.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer...

I am a...

> Eleph**ant**
>  ("Ant" is an animal, inside "Elephant", another animal)

I got a name, just gotta build it.

> Carpenter ant

Change a letter and double one that I have, roll me around, oh wait, don't take that!

> Unsure...

Alright let's come back to the big state because I'm not a fan of that!

> Unsure...

Now that we're here, let's look ahead.

> **Ant**icipate

I guess you need me before all else.

> **Ant**ecedent